# R - string manipulation

Tags: regex, r, string, gsub

I am working with a character vector produced with a 'readLines' command.

At a certain part of this vector, I have the following:

```
> metadata[147:157]
 [1] "    RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_1 = 1.2852E-02"  "    RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_2 = 1.3161E-02" 
 [3] "    RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_3 = 1.2128E-02"  "    RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_4 = 1.0227E-02" 
 [5] "    RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_5 = 6.2583E-03"  "    RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_6 = 1.5564E-03" 
 [7] "    RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_7 = 5.2458E-04"  "    RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_8 = 1.1574E-02" 
 [9] "    RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_9 = 2.4459E-03"  "    RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_10 = 3.3420E-04"
[11] "    RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_11 = 3.3420E-04"
```

What I need to to is to get only the values of each line, or better, everything that comes after the equal symbol. Something like this:

```
factor <- as.numeric (everything coming after the equal symbol (metadata[147:157]))
```

I guess this can be done with gsub, but I didn't find anything helpful in the documentation. Any ideas?

Many thanks,
Thiago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `regex`

```
as.numeric(sub(".*= ?", "", metadata))
#[1] 0.01285200 0.01316100 0.01212800 0.01022700 0.00625830 0.00155640
#[7] 0.00052458 0.01157400 0.00244590 0.00033420 0.00033420
```

#### data

```
metadata <- c("    RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_1 = 1.2852E-02", 
"    RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_2 = 1.3161E-02",
"    RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_3 = 1.2128E-02", 
"    RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_4 = 1.0227E-02",
"    RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_5 = 6.2583E-03",
"    RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_6 = 1.5564E-03", 
"    RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_7 = 5.2458E-04",
"    RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_8 = 1.1574E-02", 
"    RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_9 = 2.4459E-03",
"    RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_10 = 3.3420E-04", 
"    RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_11 = 3.3420E-04")
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. That really did the trick. I could not imagine it would be that easy...